# volatile qualifier for std::atomic<T>

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, volatile

When using an `std::atomic<T>` (let's fix `T` to `int` for simplicity), should the atomic variable be declared `volatile`?

```
std::atomic<int> x;
volatile std::atomic<int> y;
```

When would I want to use or withhold `volatile` for these? I can't seem to imagine a useful case for `std::atomic` that is not declared `volatile` unless one manually adds in compiler memory barriers.

Comment: Are you thinking of Java? Its `volatile` is a different thing.

Comment: `volatile` only guarantees that the compiler will not perform reads/writes from some cached register value. `std::atomic` not only provides that same guarantee, but also that no reordering of instructions will take places across an `atomic` variable access, which is necessary for synchronization in a multi-threaded environment (I believe MSVC provides the no reordering guarantee for `volatile` as well, but that's a compiler extension, and not portable). So it's unnecessary to declare the `atomic` variable `volatile`.

Comment: @Praetorian: That's the answer I was looking for. Thanks.